# Ember.js Controller Does not work

Tags: javascript, ember.js, controller, ember-data

I can't access to my array controller variables. I have this simple application for example:

App.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.Router.map(function() {
     this.route('hello');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('hello');
      }
});

App.HelloController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
     name: 'tom'
});

App.HelloRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
           return this.store.find('hello');
     }
});

App.Hello = DS.Model.extend({
     title: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Hello.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'hello'
},{
    id: 2,
    title: 'hello'  
}];
```

and my views are:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
<h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

{{outlet}}
</script> 


 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="hello">
  {{#each}}
     {{title}} {{name}}
   {{/each}}
 </script>
```

when i save this code the page just render "hello" "hello" and i expect "hello tom" "hello tom". What i'm doing wrong?

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're changing the context in your each statement to the model, so you no longer have the name in context.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UzUxIwa/1/edit

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="hello">
   {{#each item in controller}}
     {{item.title}} {{controller.name}}
   {{/each}}
 </script>
```

Honestly even better than this would be to use an itemController and put the property on that controller

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UzUxIwa/2/edit

```
App.HelloController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController:'singleHello'
});

App.SingleHelloController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  name: 'tom' 
});

{{#each item in controller}}
  {{item.title}} {{item.name}}</br>
{{/each}}
```