# Ember JS - Unable to get action in each to change class of div modal

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm having some major issues trying to do something that should be simple, which means that I'm obviously missing something simple.

I'm pulling articles via an API, and instead of having someone click the link to an article, I want a modal to popup with the content of the article on click, so that there wouldn't be any need for page changing or having to load the api multiple times. Naturally, the easiest way I thought of solving this was to use an action to set a property from false to true, and use that property on a bind-attr class to show the modal. However, no matter what I seem to do, I can't ever get the property value initially set or changed in the action, and logging the variable to check and see what it returns results in an error saying the variable is not defined. I would really like to see what the problem is here so I can also use this solution on my list/grid class toggling functions, because right now I resorted to using jQuery for that due to having similar problems.

Below is the code used for my articles listing and the action handling. The action does fire, which I confirmed with an alert(), but no luck on the property. Thanks for the help!

**HTML**

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="articles">
        <button {{action 'listStyle'}}>List</button>
        <button {{action 'gridStyle'}}>Grid</button>
        <section id="articles-category" class="grid">
            <div class="row">
                {{#each}}
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 article-wrapper" {{action "openArticle"}}>
                        <div class="article">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x270">
                            <div class="content">
                                <h3>{{title}}</h3>                                   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div {{bind-attr class=":article-modal isArticleActive:enabled" target="controller"}}>
                        <div class="article-close">X</div>
                        <div class="article-back">Back to Articles</div>
                        <div class="article-wrapper">
                            <div class="container">
                                <h2 class="article">{{title}}</h2>
                                {{{unescape html_body}}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </section>
    </script>
```

**app.js**

```
    // MAIN APP CONFIGURATION
    App = Ember.Application.create();

    DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
        host: 'http://mihair.herokuapp.com',
        namespace: 'api'
    });

    Ember.Handlebars.helper('unescape', function(value) {
        newValue = value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
        return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(value);
    });


    // ROUTER
    App.Router.map(function(){
        this.resource('articles', {path: ':id'});
        this.resource('article', {path: 'articles/:id_or_slug'});
    });

    App.ArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function() {
            return this.store.find('articles');
        }
    });

    App.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(params) {
            return this.store.find('articles', params.id_or_slug)
        }
    });


    // MODELS
    App.Response = DS.Model.extend({
        success: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false}),
        message: DS.attr('string')
    });

    App.Articles = DS.Model.extend({
        title: DS.attr('string'),
        description: DS.attr('string'),
        html_body: DS.attr('string')
    });

    App.Article = DS.Model.extend({
        id: DS.attr('number'),
        title: DS.attr('string'),
        description: DS.attr('string'),
        html_body: DS.attr('string')
    });


    // CONTROLLERS
    App.ArticlesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
        isArticleActive: false,
        actions: {
            listStyle: function() {
                $('#articles-category').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
            },
            gridStyle: function(){
                $('#articles-category').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
            },
            openArticle: function() {
                this.set('isArticleActive', true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isArticleActive` lives on the `ArticlesController` (which is the collection), but when you use `{{#each}}` you change the context from the controller to an individual article.  You'll want to work with an itemController in order to create properties for each item individual model instead of for the collection as a whole.

[Ember.js Controller Does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532363/ember-js-controller-does-not-work/19533390#19533390)

Comment: So how would I go about making an item controller for the each items?

Comment: I believe the other stackoverflow question shows an example, are you still confused about it?

Comment: Ahh ok, let me see if I got this correctly. I identify the name of the controller for the individual items. Then I put my actions within the single item controller? Either way, you've given me the answer that I needed, I just need to read it a few more times for my fried brain to get it, so I'll check you off. Thanks again!

Comment: I think what you're saying is correct, here's another quick example that might help (the more the merrier, right) http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pabar/1/edit

Comment: Totally. That's exactly what I was looking for. And when I followed the link you sent a few minutes ago and created the item controller for the action, bam!...started working. I've been going nuts the past 2 days over this so thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. only been working with a framework like Ember for a few days now, so definitely a lot to learn.